# Check if netsh wlan connect failed in batch script

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, batch

I'm writing a batch script that should connect to a specific wireless network and begin a download from a NAS share drive on that network.

Obviously, before any download can be performed, I must check that the machine is connected to the correct network.

**How can I check that I have connected to the correct network?**

The relevant section of my batch script is thus:

```
...

netsh wlan add profile filename=%_SCRIPT_PATH%MyWireless.xml
netsh wlan connect name=MyWireless

...
```

Where MyWireless.xml is a netsh exported network profile generated by:

```
C:\Users\Daemon>netsh wlan export profile folder=C:\Users\Daemon\ name=MyWireless
```

Comment: does netsh give you an errorlevel value which you can check in the cmd?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've just added errorlevel checking, and you are correct, netsh does give an errorlevel value. Do you want to give that as your answer so I can mark it?

Comment: No, it doesn’t. The `%errorlevel%` is about the connection _request_, not connection establishment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the errorlevel value of the netsh command and handle the result.

[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69576](https://web.archive.org/web/20130727015115/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69576)

Comment: The `%errorlevel%` being `0` means “`Connection request was completed successfully.`” as `netsh` says, not that the connection has been successfully established.

Answer (score 0):

You want to wait for a few seconds and check out the connection state of the wireless LAN interface with `netsh wlan show interfaces`. That’s what [friedrith/node-wifi](https://github.com/friedrith/node-wifi/blob/master/src/windows-current-connections.js) does.

> `netsh wlan show interfaces`

### When the connection attempt fails

```
There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wi-Fi
    Description            : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
    GUID                   : 39eaa09a-f0a0-4f24-b69d-c1c53642c266
    Physical address       : d8:f2:ca:97:d7:7c
    State                  : disconnected
    Radio status           : Hardware On
                             Software On

    Hosted network status  : Not available
```

### When it succeeds

```
There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wi-Fi
    Description            : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz
    GUID                   : 39eaa09a-f0a0-4f24-b69d-c1c53642c266
    Physical address       : d8:f2:ca:97:d7:7c
    State                  : connected
    SSID                   : F09F93A520F09F8CB9
    BSSID                  : 28:cd:c1:0e:50:82
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : 802.11n
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Connection mode        : Profile
    Channel                : 3
    Receive rate (Mbps)    : 6
    Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 6
    Signal                 : 80%
    Profile                : pico

    Hosted network status  : Not available
```

---

Note that the outputs can be in other languages than English.

[image: Japanese]
[image: Chinese]
[image: Korean]
[image: Spanish]